# Assigning strings in shared memory processes

Tags: c, string, shared-memory

I have a program that needs to share a string between two processes. I have declared a struct that contains an array of `*char`. This struct is allocated with `shmget` and `shmat` before the main process is forked.

```
typedef struct Queue
{
    int index;
    char *directory[10];
} Queue;
```

In one of the processes, I try to set the value: (`data->dir_name` is a `*char` to a string such as "/data1")

```
queue->directory[i] = data->dir_name; // Option 1
queue->directory[i] = "foo";          // Option 2
```

My question is, what is the difference between the first and second statements above? When setting the `queue->directory[i]` to `"foo"`, the other process sees it. However, passing the value `data->dir_name`, it does not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there shouldn't be a difference, are you declaring/setting them in different points of the program? the only way I can see this happening is if one process reads the data before it has been written to file by the other process.

Comment: Maybe you make `free(data->dir_name)` somewhere before using `queue->directory[i]`? Also `data->dir_name` maybe an automatic variable.

Comment: could you share more of your code, where the process is forked?

Comment: They are set in the same part of the program. I change 'code'(data->dir_name) to 'code'"foo" in the source, recompile it, and see that "foo" shows up but the value or data->dir_name does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are only assigning a pointer, not copying the string data.  In the first case you are setting the value to point to memory that the second process can't see.  When you do the first line, the pointer `data->dir_name` is put into `queue->directory[i]`, but when the other process looks at that memory address within its own memory space, the data is not there.  On the other hand, the second line puts the address of the static string `"foo"` into the variable.  Since the processes are compiled from the same source, that string is in the same place in each process's memory, so the second one can see it.

What you want to be doing is having a buffer in the struct that you `strcpy` the directory name into.    You'll need

```
char directory[10][200];
```

and

```
strcpy (queue->directory[i], data->dir_name);
```

You'll want to check that the string length is less than 200 (in this case), and report an appropriate error if it's too long.  I'm not familiar with shared memory functions to know exactly how to do a `malloc` equivalent; if you could do that; then you would copy the string into the `malloc`ed shared memory and put the pointer to it in an array like you have in your code.  From a very quick Google search though, it appears that `malloc`ing shared memory like this might not work very well.

Comment: +1 excellent point, any immediate strings are placed in the data segment of your program at compile time, even though they don't have declarations. when you fork(), the entire memory of your program is copied, including the data segment

Comment: I see what you mean. What I'd like to do is have a data structure (2D array possibly?) that will contain an index to a string value. Similar to a Map<Integer,String> in java. I don't want the char *directory[10]; to be limited to 10 characters, I want there to only be 10 entries allowed.

Comment: `strncpy` is not the best solution. It can easily leave an array without a terminating `'\0'` null character (i.e., not a string).

Comment: @KeithThompson You're quite right, and since there's nothing useful to do if the string is too long, I've updated my answer to reflect this.